# OperationalError when trying to get the url page

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to get an url that contains some data from my database, but I keep getting this error:

```
 self = <django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.SQLiteCursorWrapper object at 0x7f01c35c2d38>
query = '        SELECT cust.id, cust.name, inv.currency_id, SUM(inv.total)\n        FROM\n          v3_customer as cust\n    ...        and inv.invoice_date < ?\n        GROUP BY cust.id, inv.currency_id\n        ORDER BY cust.id, inv.currency_id'
params = [(1,), '2016-12-04']

    def execute(self, query, params=None):
        if params is None:
            return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
        query = self.convert_query(query)
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
E       sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

../../../environments/tracerenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py:337: OperationalError
```

This is my code:

```
response = admin_client.post(
        reverse('report_create') + '?report_type=1',
        {

            'start_date': datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=180),
            'end_date': datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=180),
        }
    )
    print(admin_client.get(Report.objects.first().get_absolute_url()))
```

I found it here where it fails:

```
 PRE_INV_Q = """\
    SELECT cust.id, cust.name, inv.currency_id, SUM(inv.total)
    FROM
      v3_customer as cust
      JOIN v3_customerproxy ON cust.id = v3_customerproxy.original_id
      JOIN v3_invoice as inv ON v3_customerproxy.id = inv.customer_id
    WHERE
      cust.id IN %s
      and inv.type = 'i'
      and inv.invoice_date < %s
    GROUP BY cust.id, inv.currency_id
    ORDER BY cust.id, inv.currency_id
```

Comment: Maybe remove the `?` at `inv.invoice_data < ?\n`?

Comment: you refering to inv.invoice_date ?

Comment: Please include the full traceback, and the `report_create` view.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you `convert_query` method is only substituting the params in the query. Please try and use `%s` instead of `?`.

Comment: where is it located? (sorry I am new to this)

Comment: In your SQL query in the part: `inv.invoice_date < ?\n `. Replace `?` to `%s`. so it should be: `inv.invoice_date < %s\n`.

Comment: there are no "?" symbol

Comment: I think you have edited the question. Otherwise it is there in the first section of the question you have posted, in `query`. Is the problem still occurring to you?

Comment: yes it is. I only added the hard coded sql statement

Comment: How are you substituting values in the `query`. Ideally it should be:
`your_query_string % (some_cust_id, some_invoice_date)`. Python takes the arguments to the string formatting sequentially i.e. first it will substitute `id` and then `invoice_id`. Please check if you are doing it in correct format or not.